# how can i tell if certain cases of the type of a parameter are effectively unused?

Tags: typescript

given a function:

```
function fn(x: A | B | C): void { /*...*/ }
```

that is called from 30 places, each of which is called from 10 places, each of which is called from 5 places

how can i tell if case `A` is used or not used without spending hours checking all possible routes to function `fn` through the code?

Comment: remove `A` from the union in the definition of `fn()` and see what breaks?

Comment: it will require removing it from 30 * 10 * 5 places

Comment: @TridentD'Gao, why? Just change the function to `function fn(x: B | C): void { /*...*/ }` and compile